# Checking all elements of char array

Tags: c++, arrays, stream, char

I am having a stringstream, and I am having 8 char arrays as:

```
char str1[4] = "2001";
char str2[4] = "677F";
char str3[4] = "0000";
char str4[4] = "4004";

stringstream ss;
ss << str1;
ss << str2;
ss << str3;
ss << str4;
```

I do not want to add the arrays in the stringstream whose all the elements are zeros i.e, str1,str2 and str4 should only be added str3 should not be added in the stream.

Also if the leading char arrays are only having zeros I have to replace them by (:), something like IPv6 addresses:

**2001:0db8:0070:0040:0000:0000:0000:0000**

**2001:0db8:0070:0040::**

How can I do it?

Comment: Note that the string literals you are using have 5 elements, not 4.

Comment: Is there a reason you are using a `stringstream`?

Comment: @juanchopanza Oh yes, my bad. They are 5 elements

Answer (score 1):

You want to scan through the string, and if you find anything other than a `'0'`, you can stop and append the string to the stream. If you reach the end of the stream, and you've found nothing but `'0'`s, you don't do anything.

```
void appendIfNotZero(stringstream &stream, char *str)
{
    char *ptr = str;
    // If *ptr == 0, we've reached the end of the string.
    while(*ptr) {
        // If *ptr != '0', the string is not all zeros, and we're done.
        if(*ptr != '0') {
            stream << str;
            return;
        }
        // Otherwise, keep scanning the string.
        ptr++;
    }
}

...

appendIfNotZero(ss, "2001");
appendIfNotZero(ss, "677F");
appendIfNotZero(ss, "0000");
appendIfNotZero(ss, "4004");
```

Comment: If I get two continous char array which are zero than I have to replace with :, how to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

Simplifying godels a little.

```
char str1[] = "2001";
stringstream buffer;
string item = str1; 
if ( item != "0000" ){
   buffer << item;
}
// same for str2-4.
```

Having the strN in an array would simplify things further.

Comment: @Prats The question is now very hard to understand. What do you want?